# After selecting dropdown, some values need to show and rest of need to be hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

When I selcted the drop down, the below function is executing correctly but I need it more optimized, can any1 help me in this, because selected dropdown is coming with more keys.

```
$(".selcted").change(function () {
            var selectedEventType = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
            // alert(selectedEventType);
            if (selectedEventType == "expertise"){
                $('.fix').css("display", "block");
                $('.Nut').css("display", "block");
                $('.pra').css("display", "block");
                $('.res').css("display", "block");
                $('.equal').css("display", "block");
            } else if (selectedEventType == "equal") {
                $('.fix').css("display", "none");
                $('.Nut').css("display", "none");
                $('.pra').css("display", "none");
                $('.res').css("display", "none");
                $('.equal').css("display", "block");
            } else if (selectedEventType == "fix") {
                $('.equal').css("display", "none");
                $('.Nut').css("display", "none");
                $('.pra').css("display", "none");
                $('.res').css("display", "none");
                $('.fix').css("display", "block");
            } else if (selectedEventType == "Nut") {
                $('.equal').css("display", "none");
                $('.fix').css("display", "none");
                $('.pra').css("display", "none");
                $('.res').css("display", "none");
                $('.Nut').css("display", "block");
            } else if (selectedEventType == "pra") {
                $('.equal').css("display", "none");
                $('.fix').css("display", "none");
                $('.Nut').css("display", "none");
                $('.res').css("display", "none");
                $('.pra').css("display", "block");
            } else if (selectedEventType == "res") {
                $('.equal').css("display", "none");
                $('.fix').css("display", "none");
                $('.Nut').css("display", "none");
                $('.pra').css("display", "none");
                $('.res').css("display", "block");
            }
        });
```

Selected Statement is this

```
 <select class="elect" >
                    <option value="<%= option.val %>">
                        <%= option.lab %>  //values will come into this
                    </option>
                    <% }); %>
                </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work as you expect

Please note you have some class miss match. you call selector in your code is spelled `.selcted` but your html is `class="elect"`

```js
$(".select").change(function() {
  var selectedEventType = $(this).val()
  console.log(selectedEventType)
  // alert(selectedEventType);
  if (selectedEventType == "expertise") {
    $('.fix').css("display", "block");
    $('.Nut').css("display", "block");
    $('.pra').css("display", "block");
    $('.res').css("display", "block");
    $('.equal').css("display", "block");
  } else {
    $('.fix').css("display", "none");
    $('.Nut').css("display", "none");
    $('.pra').css("display", "none");
    $('.res').css("display", "none");
    $('.equal').css("display", "none");
    $('.' + selectedEventType).css("display", "block");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select">
      <option value="expertise">expertise
      </option>
      <option value="equal">equal
      </option>
      <option value="fix">fix
      </option>
      <option value="Nut">Nut
      </option>
      <option value="pra">pra
      </option>
      <option value="res">res
      </option>
  </select>
  
  <div class="fix">fix</div>
  <div class="Nut">Nut</div>
  <div class="pra">pra</div>
  <div class="res">res</div>
  <div class="equal">equal</div>
```